# AFNetworking & Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, afnetworking, access-token, bearer-token

I'm using AFNetwork to send a video clip to YouTube however I don't know anything about bearer of token ID's. I've edited the code to work with `AFNetworking` v3 but I'm not sure how to set up the token and bearer neither do I know what they are? I've gone onto google and set them up and have included them in the code. However I've deleted parts of the codes so my account isn't stolen. ;)

How do you use Bear and Tokens? :(

```
+(void) sendYoutube:(fileuploadinfo *)info{

    //tpg...-144...
    //AIzaSyDDO4EwR...........X7T9cmiqBsgU

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Bearer #_token_goes_here#" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"snippet" : @{@"title" : @"random_title",
                                                @"description" : @"random_description"}};
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Bearer Token` is set in the Authorization header of every Inline Action HTTP Request. As stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2),

> [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) is a standard specification for allowing end users to securely authorize a client application to access protected server-side resources. In addition, the [**OAuth 2.0 bearer token**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) specification explains how to access those protected resources using an access token granted during the end-user authorization process.

[Example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/verifying-bearer-tokens):

```
POST /rsvp?eventId=123 HTTP/1.1
Host: events-organizer.com
Authorization: Bearer AbCdEf123456
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/1.0 (KHTML, like Gecko; Gmail Actions)

rsvpStatus=YES
```

Wherein the string `AbCdEf123456` in the example above is the bearer authorization token. It is a cryptographic token produced by Google. All bearer tokens sent with actions are have the `issuee` field as `gmail@system.gserviceaccount.com` and the audience the sender domain as an `https://` url. For example, if the email is from `noreply@example.com`, the audience is `https://example.com`.

You can also check this [reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) which might help.